# Split string and extract text and number

Tags: java, regex, string, spring-boot

I have to divide an address into street and number. Examples

```
Lievensberg 31D
Jablunkovska 21/2
Weimarstraat 113 A
Pastoor Baltesenstraat 22
Van Musschenboek strasse 84
```

I need to split like this:

```
Street1: Lievensberg
Number1: 31D

Street2: Jablunkovska
Number2: 21/2

Street3: Weimarstraat
Number3: 113 A

Street4: Pastoor Baltesenstraat
Number4: 22

Street5: Van Musschenboek strasse
Number5: 84
```

I used this code but not working, because I need to split only when the character after the white space will be a number:

```
String[] arrSplit = address_line.split("\\s");   
for (int i = 0; i < arrSplit.length; i++) {     
    System.out.println(arrSplit[i]);   
}
```

But I don't know how to do it so that all my requirements are met. Any idea?

Comment: `address_line.split("\\s+(?=\\d)")`

Comment: If the digits are optional, use 2 capturing groups `^([^\d\r\n]+?)(?:\h*(\d.*)|$)` https://regex101.com/r/QzStl2/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number can be optional, instead of using split, you could use 2 capturing groups where the second group is optional.

```
^([^\d\r\n]+?)(?:\h*(\d.*)|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `([^\d\r\n]+?)` Match 1+ times any char except a digit or newline non greedy
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\h*(\d.*)` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `$` End of string
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8GIjto/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/LGCThe)

Example code

```
String regex = "^([^\\d\\r\\n]+?)(?:\\h*(\\d.*)|$)";
String string = "Lievensberg 31D\n"
 + "Jablunkovska 21/2\n"
 + "Weimarstraat 113 A\n"
 + "Pastoor Baltesenstraat 22\n"
 + "Van Musschenboek strasse 84\n"
 + "Lievensberg";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Street: " + matcher.group(1));
    if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
        System.out.println("Number: " + matcher.group(2));  
    }
    System.out.println("------------------");
}
```

Output

```
Street: Lievensberg
Number: 31D
------------------
Street: Jablunkovska
Number: 21/2
------------------
Street: Weimarstraat
Number: 113 A
------------------
Street: Pastoor Baltesenstraat
Number: 22
------------------
Street: Van Musschenboek strasse
Number: 84
------------------
Street: Lievensberg
------------------
```

Comment: your code serves me perfect thanks! but could you help me adapt your code to these examples? They are extra examples, so the above must also be met: "ul. Piłsjjeizhsa 73k/1209", "Lamgresülat sóténzs 3., 729. tömbház F 2.", "Schzelkjedow 12Z / 48". "Erchrhe, 07/83, 9", "Alopmes Pulkschcow  Walksehsdfich 244/093", "Gagarina 3/5/7 m 344"

Comment: Perhaps like this? `https://regex101.com/r/gcHn9H/1`

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I created this other, maybe you can help me too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027691/split-string-in-3-blocks-text-number-other-characters-if-possible Wil be nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to verify first whether it matches or not, then only process it.

```
String str1 = "Lievensberg 31D"; // street = Lievensberg, number = 31D
String str2 = "Lievensberg NN31D"; // doesn't matches
String str3 = "Lievensberg"; // street = Lievensberg, number = null
String str4 = "Pastoor Baltesenstraat 22"; // street = Pastoor Baltesenstraat, number = 22


Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z ]+?)(\\s(\\d+)(.*))?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str1);
if(matcher.matches()) {
    String street = matcher.group(1);
    String number = matcher.group(2) != null ? matcher.group(3) + matcher.group(4) : null;
    System.out.println("street = " + street);
    System.out.println("number = " + number);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Only one question, if I receive the str = "Lievensberg" the code dont send to me the street name. how can I fix it using your code?

Comment: You mentioned in the question `I need to split only when the character after the white space will be a number:` In that case need to modify the regex.

Comment: I don't know very well how to handle regular expressions, would you help me adapt that example (only street namer without spaces)?

Comment: Handled multi word street name as well. Just it requires street name to contain a-zA-Z and space only ()

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("Lievensberg 31D");
    list.add("Jablunkovska 21/2");
    list.add("Weimarstraat 113 A");
    list.add("Pastoor Baltesenstraat 22");
    list.add("Van Musschenboek strasse 84");
    
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){     
        System.out.println("Street"+(i+1)+": "+ list.get(i).split("\\s+(?=\\d)")[0]);
        System.out.println("Number"+(i+1)+": "+ list.get(i).split("\\s+(?=\\d)")[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic:

1. Find the index of the first number
2. Split the string based on this index

For better understanding use below code
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String address_line = "Weimarstraat 113 A";
    
    // Find index of first number
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(address_line);
    int i = -1;
    for(char c: address_line.toCharArray() ){
        if('0'<=c && c<='9')
            break;
            
        i++;
    }
        
    //Split string using index
    System.out.println(address_line.substring(0, i));
    System.out.println(address_line.substring(i+1));
    
}
```

Its output will be:

```
Weimarstraat                                                                                                                                                  
113 A
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple solution using regex and split:

```
String str = "Jablunkovska 21/2";
String[] split = str.split("\\s(?=\\d)", 2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Output:

```
[Jablunkovska, 21/2]
```

The expression `(?=\\d)` is a lookahead for a digit, so it doesn't get removed with the split.