# Split string in 3 blocks (Text - Number - Other characters) if possible

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot

I need to divide a string into 3 blocks at most

- The first block is only for letters
- The second only numbers
- The third the remainder

**Examples**:

```
Karbwqeaf 11D
Jablunkovska 21/2
Tastoor Nstraat 43
Schzelkjedow
Heajsd 3/5/7 m 344
Lasdasdt seavees 3., 729. tasdasd F 2.
ul. Pasydufasdfa 73k/120
```

I need to split like this:

```
Block1: Karbwqeaf
Block2: 11
Block3: D

Block1: Jablunkovska
Block2: 21
Block3: /2

Block1: Tastoor Nstraat
Block2: 43
Block3: 

Block1: Schzelkjedow
Block2: 
Block3: 

Block1: Heajsd
Block2: 3
Block3: /5/7 m 344

Block1: Lasdasdt seavees 3
Block2: 3
Block3: ., 729. tasdasd F 2.

Block1: ul. Pasydufasdfa
Block2: 73
Block3: k/120
```

Below my code, but I don't know how to do it so that all my requirements are met. Any idea?

```
List<String> AllAddress = Arrays.asList("Karbwqeaf 11D", "Jablunkovska 21/2", "Tastoor Nstraat 43", "Schzelkjedow", "Heajsd 3/5/7 m 344", "Lasdasdt seavees 3., 729. tasdasd F 2.", "ul. Pasydufasdfa 73k/120");

for (String Address : AllAddress) {
    String block1 = "";
    String block2 = "";
    String block3 = "";
        
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\s(\\d)(.*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Address);
    if(matcher.matches()) {
        block1 = matcher.group(1);
        block2 = matcher.group(2);
        block3 = matcher.group(3);
        System.out.println("block1 = " + block1);
        System.out.println("block2 = " + block2);
        System.out.println("block3 = " + block3);
    }
}
```

Comment: change your regex in `([^\\d]+)\\s(\\d)?\\s?(.*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 3 capturing groups, where the second group matches 1 or more digits and the 3rd group matches any character 0+ times.

```
^([^\d\r\n]+)(?:\h+(\d+)(.*))?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^\d\r\n]+` Match any char except a newline or digit
- `)` Close **group 1**
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
  - `(\d+)(.*)` Capture 1 or more digits in **group 2** and capture 0 or more times any character in **group 3**
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J4VPey/1)